# "А был ли мальчик?"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда в русском языке взялась поговорка "А был ли мальчик?"

Comment: Это не поговорка. Это типичный *мем*. Примерно как "дитям - мороженое, бабе его - цветы". Поговоркой, наверное, всё-таки можно считать только фразу, полностью утратившую связь с литературным источником.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выражение это впервые появилось в книге Максима Горького "Жизнь Клима Самгина". Когда главный герой пытался спасти провалившегося под лед мальчика, он сперва бросил ему конец ремня, но потом испугался, что тот утянет его под воду, ремень забрал. Мальчик утонул.
Позже взрослые, анализируя ситуацию, говорили: "А был ли мальчик? А может, мальчика-то и не было?"

Answer (score 1):

Из истории. Принадлежит Борису Годунову. После смерти царевича Ивана у Ивана Грозного оставался только один наследник - царевич Федор, но он был слаб здоровьем. Борису Годунову удалось выдать за него замуж свою сестру - Ирину. В то время Иван Грозный был женат на красавице Соломонии Сабуровой, но она оказалась бесплодной и не смогла подарить царю наследника. За это ее отправили в ссылку, в дальний монастырь. Но через несколько месяцев оттуда пришла весть, что у Соломонии родился сын - царевич Дмитрий. Иван Грозный поручил Борису Годунову разобраться в этом деле. Борис отправил в монастырь своих людей, но те скоро вернулись и сообщили страшную весть, что якобы младенец нечаянно упал на нож (ножницы) и умер. Многие тогда приписывали "нечаянную смерть" младенца Борису Годунову, как наиболее заинтересованному в таком исходе, так как после смерти Ивана Грозного, Ирина становилась царицей, а сам Борис фактическим правителем России, как шурин немощного царя. В общем так оно и вышло в последствии. Когда Бориса стали обвинять в убийстве младенца, то он отговаривался "А были-ли мальчик?" вообще. Но до самой смерти самому Борису Годунову "кровавые мальчики" в глазах мерещились. До сих пор историкам не известно был-ли царевич Дмитрий или нет на самом деле, или это просто Соломония Сабурова так отомстила за опалу Ивану Грозному.

Comment: А ведь правильно. Вполне возможная версия.